# Build GlobalPlatform for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, openssl, globalplatform, gpshell

I try building GlobalPlatform for Ubuntu 14.04LTS to get GPShell up and running.

but I get the following errors. I think this is openssl related but I'm not 100% sure.

> crypto.c:1391:17: error: storage size of ‘ctx’ isn’t known
>   EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
>
> ^ crypto.c:1391:17: warning: unused variable ‘ctx’ [-Wunused-variable] make[1]: *** [libglobalplatform_la-crypto.lo]
>   Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   `/usr/local/bin/globalplatform-6.0.0/src' make: *** [check-recursive]
>
> Error 1

I used the current openssl Version 1.1.0.
I also removed it and tried to build openssl 0.9.8g as recommended by GlobalPlatform, but I cannot build it as it's 32bit I think as it crashes with the following error:

> md5-x86_64.s:580: Error: 0xbd3af235 out range of signed 32bit displacement md5-x86_64.s:598:
>
> Error: 0xeb86d391 out range of signed
>
> 32bit displacement make[2]: *** [md5-x86_64.o] Error 1

Comment: Use OpenSSL 1.0.2 rather than OpenSSL 1.1.0.

Comment: @jww i can build 1.0.2 stable, but the ctx stays