# What is CPLC (Card Product Life Cycle data) ? What is the use of CPLC in NFC enabled smartphone?

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, secure-element

If we go to NFC SE option in any smartphone that supports NFC then, CPLC number is displayed. Its a very long number starting with 9F7F. What is that number, what is its importance?

Answer (score 1):

This source ([GlobalPlatform Card Specification](https://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/wiki/GlobalPlatform%20Card%20Specification/)) explains:

Card Data

There is a variety of card data objects. The Open Platform specification proposes only that the CPLC
data should be retrievable. CPLC is an abbreviation for Card Production Life Cycle. This data object
contains information about the production process of the card like the operating system or the ICC
manufacturer. The Card issuer BIN data contains usually the serial number of the card. Apart from that
the user defined Card issuer data can be used e.g. for deriving the keys. Some other possible values can
be the available resources like EEPROM space.

In the answer to a similar question ([Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238382/how-do-i-get-cplc-data-from-a-smart-card)) is some info about the meaning of the number:

/**

- Whole CPLC data from ROM and EEPROM.
- 9F7F // TAG
- 2A // Length of data
- ////////////////Data /////////////
- 4250 // ic fabricator
- 3272 // ic type
- 1291 // os id
- 6181 // os date
- 0700 // os level
- 8039 // fabrication date
- 0106D0BB // ic serial
- 1D3C // ic batch
- 0000 // module fabricator
- 8148 // packing date
- 0000// icc manufacturer
- 8148 // ic embedding date
- 0000 // pre - personalizer
- 0000 // IC Pre Personalization Date
- 00000000 //IC Pre Personalization Equipment Identifier
- 0000// IC Personalizer
- 0000 // IC Personalization Date
- 00000000 // IC Personalization Equipment Identifier
  */